# RapidXml fails to parse xml which has unicode containts

Tags: c++, xml, windows, unicode, rapidxml

I am trying to parse xml which has Unicode chars but rapidxml is giving exception when I call parse function.

Attaching code snippet.

Note: Same code is able to parse ascii containt.

```
bool
ParseXmlData(const std::wstring &XmlData)
{
    LPCTSTR thisMethod = L"ParseXmlData()";
    wchar_t* wc_xmlstring = wcsdup(XmlData.c_str());

    xml_document<wchar_t> xmldoc;

    try
    {
        xmldoc.parse<0>(wc_xmlstring);
    }
    catch (rapidxml::parse_error &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what()
        free (dupStr);
       return false;
    }

    -
    -
    -
    -
    return true
}
```

Comment: what kind of exception do you get? and what is input value that your are trying to test?

Comment: I am getting this error : expected ' or "

Comment: I am having Korean character in my xml. You can use this content where my code is failing, 
< path="\\home\조선글"/>

More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with your input, though it is not reproduced with every Korean character.
It turns out that rapidxml has [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/rapidxml/bugs/23/) when parsing characters outside look up table size.

You can find full patch [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/rapidxml/bugs/_discuss/thread/331bbf2b/4d88/attachment/rapidxml_wchar_t.diff). I have verified that problem is fixed after applying this patch.
Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Another option is to use UTF8 encoding - RapidXML should work just fine with that.

Comment: @Roddy Due to some reasons, we have to send the data in unicode format only.